# List files of a directory with client-server java program

Tags: java, client-server

I'm working on Eclipse (so Java) to write a server-client that accept client input to do upload, download and list of some files (list of the entire directory). I'm working on the last command but I'm not sure if it works because I don't know how to start it from the client part. I know there is a bug at the level of the file directory because I don't know how to initialize it. If I initialize with "null" then I will have a "NullPointerException". If I don't initialize it, then I have to initialize the variable... Maybe is there a better way to solve the problem? Thanks to everyone

```
File directory;
PrintWriter outgoing;
String[] fileList = directory.list();
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
    outgoing.println(fileList[i]);
}
    outgoing.flush();
    outgoing.close();
    if (outgoing.checkError()){
        throw new Exception("Error while transmitting data.");
    }
```

(Just to be precise, this section is in the server section. I initialize the function with the Terminal. Then at the beginning it works but then, when I try to initialize the client I receive the errors I explained above)

Comment: What directory do you want to list ? the one the client program is running in ?

Comment: The variables directory and outgoing are not initialized. Resolve this first.

Comment: Yes. I have server and client on one directory. With them I have some files (line photo and pdf) and I want to print a list of this directory where there are also my java client-server (sorry @ortis you are right, I forget to do it)

Comment: Thanks @MirecXP. As you can see in my question, I explained it already...  I know there is a bug at the level of the file directory because I don't know how to initialize it. If I initialize with "null" then I will have a "NullPointerException". If I don't initialize it, then I have to initialize the variable...

Comment: e.g.:
File directory = new File("c:/temp");
PrintWriter outgoing = new PrintWriter(System.out);

Comment: To get the current directory of the program, use `File directory = new File(".")`

Comment: Ok @ortis that's good. Do you have something for outgoing? Can I leave it as outgoing = null?

Comment: Because if I leave it as null (as I already explained) I will have a NullPointerException

Comment: listen to @MirecXP ! Using the constructors of File and PrintWrite will solve the problem.

Comment: I will merge the solutions. For the outgoing it could be ok but for the directory I want to do something general so I will use ortis'solution

Comment: Amazing. Thanks to @MirecXP and to ortis for it. It works.